# war card game simulation in python

Tags: python, simulation, game-engine

Hi you might remember this program if you are a regular here. I have solved many of the bugs but am stumped by one. The error is:

```
File "/Users/administrator/Desktop/war.py", line 62, in <module>
    player1.extend(player1[range(warcardvalue1)])
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not list
```

the code is:

```
import random

cards = ['ace', 'ace', 'ace', 'ace', '1', '1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '2', '2', '3', '3', '3', '3', '4', '4', '4', '4', '5', '5', '5', '5', '6', '6', '6', '6', '7', '7', '7', '7', '8', '8', '8', '8', '9', '9', '9', '9', '10', '10', '10', '10', 'jack', 'jack', 'jack', 'jack', 'queen', 'queen', 'queen', 'queen', 'king', 'king', 'king', 'king']

order = ['ace', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'jack', 'queen', 'king'] 
warcardvalue0 = 0
warcardvalue1 = 0
print "shuffling cards" 
random.shuffle(cards)
print "lets play"

player0 = cards[1::2]

player1 = cards[::2]

while (len(player0) > 0 or len(player1) > 0):

    nextcard0 = player0[0]
    nextcard1 = player1[0]

    cardplayed0 = order.index(nextcard0)

    cardplayed1 = order.index(nextcard1)

    if cardplayed0 > cardplayed1:

        player0.append(nextcard0)
        player0.append(nextcard1)
        player0.remove(nextcard0)
        player1.remove(nextcard1)

    elif cardplayed0 < cardplayed1:

        player1.append(nextcard1)
        player1.append(nextcard0)
        player1.remove(nextcard1)
        player0.remove(nextcard0)

    elif cardplayed0 == cardplayed1:
        while warcardvalue0 == warcardvalue1:
            if len(player0) >= 3:
                        warcard0 = player0[3]
                elif len(player0) < 3:
                    warcard0 = player0[len(player0)-1]

            if len(player1) >= 3:
                        warcard1 = player1[3]
                elif len(player1) < 3:
                    warcard1 = player1[len(player1)-1]


            warcardvalue0 = order.index(warcard0)
            warcardvalue1 = order.index(warcard1)

            if warcardvalue0 > warcardvalue1:
                player0.extend(player0[range(warcardvalue0)])
                player0.extend(player1[range(warcardvalue1)])
                player0.extend(player0[range(warcardvalue0)])
                player1.extend(player1[range(warcardvalue1)]) 

            elif warcardvalue0 < warcardvalue1:
                player1.extend(player1[range(warcardvalue1)])
                player1.extend(player0[range(warcardvalue0)])
                player1.extend(player1[range(warcardvalue1)])
                player0.extend(player0[range(warcardvalue0)]) 
            else:
                print "another war!" 


if len(player1) == 0:
    print "player1 won!"
elif len(player0) == 0:
    print "player0 won!"
```

I think the problem is that you cant use range in lists but I'm not sure.

Comment: The error is just what it says.  `range` returns a list.  You can't use a list as an index into another list.  Explain what you're trying to achieve with `player1[range(warcardvalue1)]`.

Comment: You probably want [slice notation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/good-primer-for-python-slice-notation).

Comment: May I recommend http://code.activestate.com/recipes/sets/13/ if you are interested in a Python version of War Game?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think the problem is that you cant use range in lists but I'm not sure.

The problem is that you can't index a list with a list.

Try this instead:

```
player1.extend(player1[:warcardvalue1])
```

Seems a bit odd to want to do it though....

Comment: now im receiving this error: File "/Users/administrator/Desktop/war.py", line 58, in <module>
    player0.remove(player0[x] for x in range(warcardvalue0))
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list

Comment: @A.Collins: That's a different line. It's not related to your original error. This should help you: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Python/List/Listdeleteaslice2.htm